# How to use external build system for Visual C++ 2013 project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, custom-build

Is it possible to use an `external build system` for VC++ 2013? 
I want Visual Studio do nothing but build by invoking my build tools.

I am thinking about something like this:

- Put all build command in batches.
- Invoke a project-level build batch by right clicking the project and choose build.
- Invoke the a solution-level build batch by right clicking the solution and choose build.

  Is there some walk-through tutorial? I searched a lot but no luck.

### ADD 1  - Some progress...

After briefly reading about the `MSBuild` process, I tried as below.

First, I edit the `*.vcxproj` project file. I change the `DefaultTargets` from `Build` to `MyTarget`.

```
<Project DefaultTargets="MyTarget" ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

Then I add a new target named `MyTarget`:

```
  <Target Name="MyTarget">
    <Message Text="Hello, Bitch!" />
  </Target>
```

I hope this can bypass the VS2013 built-in built process and only carry out my own batch.

It works well on command prompt:

[image]

But in Visual Studio, when I right click the project and choose `build` command, it gives me a lot of link errors.

How to avoid these link errors? Since my batch can take care of all the build process, I don't need Visual Studio to do the link for me.

### ADD 2

It seems these link errors show up because I include the `*.c` files with the `ClCompile` tag as below.

```
<ItemGroup>
   <ClCompile Include="z:\MyProject1\source1.c" />
<ItemGroup>
```

Since I don't want VS2013 to invoke the compiler, I change it to `<ClInclude>` tag, the link errors disappeared, but the symbol resolution is not working... Seems I shouldn't change the tag.

### ADD 3

Here's another way to compile without linking.

[Is it possible for Visual Studio C++ to compile objects without linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347927/is-it-possible-for-visual-studio-c-to-compile-objects-without-linking)

Seems it doesn't have the symbol resolution issue. But I still cannot invoke an external batch by click `build/rebuild/clean`.

Comment: And a related link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32785764/how-to-programmatically-create-a-vc-project-with-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into Visual Studio's makefile projects (in the Visual C++/General project templates category).

You get to specify what commands to execute for each type of build (clean, build, rebuild).  The command can invoke a make, run a batch file, or invoke some other build tool.  It just executes a command.  The commands can contain various macros that VS provides (similar to environment variables) so the command can be parametrized for things like making a target directory based on the solution or project name or type (debug vs. release).

Comment: The `Makefile` project .vcxproj file is much cleaner. And it seems much easier to extend it. I will try it. Thanks!

Comment: By default, the build log file name is set to `$(IntDir)$(MSBuildProjectName).log`, so the Debug build log should end up in `"Debug\project-name.log"`.  You can customize the location/name in the project settings `"General|Build Log File"` field.

Comment: You suggestion pointed out a better direction. I am marking it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

(Michael Burr's reply pointed out a better direction, i.e. a better VC++ project template. You can combine my answer and his.)

Finally, I solved this issue!

The trick is the so-called `target overriding`. The Visual Studio context menu items `Build\Rebuild\Clean` correspond to MSBuild targets named `Build\Rebuild\Clean`, respectively. We just need to override them in the `*.vcxproj` file.

Such as this:

[image]

DO REMEMBER that:

> The last target seen by MSBuild is the one that is used — this is why
>   we put the  at the end of the existing *.vcxproj file.

And in the `override.proj`, do whatever you like as below:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="Build">
    <Message Text="Build override!" />
    <Exec Command="kickass.bat" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

The following 2 links are good reference:

1. [Hack the build](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jomo_fisher/archive/2004/09/16/230631.aspx)
2. [Hijacking the Visual Studio Build Process](http://sedodream.com/2013/06/01/HijackingTheVisualStudioBuildProcess.aspx)

Note that:

- The 1st link take a CSharp project as example, but ALSO works with VC++ project.
- The 2nd link doesn't work for VC++ project but the rational is similar. If you didn't include the `Microsoft.Cpp.targets`, you will see the following error when loading the project:

[image]

### ADD 1

As I tried, we don't need another `overrride.proj` file. We can just place the specific target at the end of the `*.vcxprj` file. Such as below:

[image]

### ADD 2

With `target overriding` mentioned above, I can run my customized `bat` file with `project's` Build/Rebuild/Clean commands. But I noticed that when I run `solution's` Build/Rebuild/Clean commands, I think it is just following some kind of `project dependency order` to build each project respectively, which is not exactly equivalent to what I want for an `overall build` in my scenario.

My current workaround is to create a `dummy project` and use it to trigger a batch for my `overall` build.

Comment: And a related link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32785764/how-to-programmatically-create-a-vc-project-with-c